# ¿Cómo insertar datos en tablas realcionadas en mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Mi duda seria la de como ingresar datos a distintas tablas relacionadas en Mysql.
Las tablas que quiero relacionar son "alumno" y "domicilio" ,a continuación pongo el código en php.

imagen de mi base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
session_start();
include_once 'connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $reg_tsp = $_POST['nombre_a'];
    $detalle_ftsp = $_POST['apellido_a'];
    $apellido_a = $_POST['dni_a'];
    $nombre_a = $_POST['celular_a'];
    $dni_a = $_POST['email_a'];
    $detalle_dom = $_POST['detalle_dom'];
    


//esta sección esta de ejemplo ,obviamente aquí es donde quiero una solución
    $sql = "INSERT INTO alumno,domicilio (nombre_a,apellido_a,dni_a,celular_a,email_a,detalle_dom)
    VALUES('$nombre_a','$apellido_a','$dni_a','$celular_a','$email_a','$detalle_dom')";


//Usar para MySQL
    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Datos almacenados correctamente';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Algo salió mal al agregar el registro';
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Rellena el formulario de agregar primero';
}

header('location: index.php');
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o error?

Comment: Creo que no es posible hacerlo con un solo insert

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer 2 inserciones, después de insertar el registro de alumno obtén el `id` que se le asigno y lo agregas al query de insert a la tabla de domicilio

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO alumno (nombre_a,apellido_a,dni_a,celular_a,email_a) VALUES ('$nombre_a','$apellido_a','$dni_a','$celular_a','$email_a')";
    
        if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    
            $id_alumno = $conn->insert_id;

            $sql_detalle = "INSERT INTO domicilio (detalle_dom, detalle_id_alumno) VALUES('$detalle_dom', $id_alumno )";
            $conn->query($sql_detalle);
    
            $_SESSION['success'] = 'Datos almacenados correctamente';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Algo salió mal al agregar el registro';
        }
```

Debes tener un campo detalle_id_alumno en la tabla domicilio para la relación.

Comment: agregue mi base de datos ,ya realice los pasos que asignaste el código corre pero no guarda nada :(

Comment: No habías agregado la estructura de tu tabla, por lo que veo primero debes agregar la dirección y obtener el id, después insertar el alumno pero por lo que veo tienes otras foreign key donde debes hacer lo mismo que en dirección.

Comment: Si mi estimado ya realice eso y elimine el resto de llaves foráneas para hacer la prueba de que funcionara solo en esas dos tablas pero el caso es el mismo la consulta me corre perfectamente pero no me guarda ningún valor ,pero pasa algo curioso cuando intento agregar un dato manualmente desde XAMPP se realiza salteándose un id en mi tabla por ejemplo si en mi tabla esta llenado hasta el id 5 mi inserción de datos se realiza en el id 7 y el id 6 se rellena automático ,espero haberme dejado entender